# How to select the UITableViewCell from top to bottom in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to `Objective C`. I am having the UITableView in that I have to select the `tableview` cell from top to bottom also without selecting the first cell the second cell won't be selected and the user won't able to select the in-between cells also.can anyone help me how to solve this?
 I added the example image here if the user selected the first cell the second cell want to enable and if the user selects the second cell the third cell want to enable remaining cells want to disable.

[image]

[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.colors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Red", @"Yellow", @"Green",
                       @"Blue", @"Purpole", nil];
    }


    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        return [self.colors count];
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                                 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.textLabel.text = [self.colors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: you need to write again what do you want to do? draw it or something

Comment: better you explain with real scenario...

Comment: thanks for your reply i edited my question as part of your request

Comment: @user19 please update with real code for show selected or deselected functionality with `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, Hope you have an issue with making multiple cell selection:
Allow `UITableView` to select multiple cells by `tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true;`. And then a user can select any number of cells in the table.

Comment: thanks for your answer i edited my question as part of your request.i needed multiple selection from top to bottom without selecting the first cell the user should not able to select the next cell.

Comment: you need to move your column titles to UITableView header, then you will not get the check mark for column title row. Otherwise, if you wish to go with the same then use `UITableView Delegate` `tableView:( didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and check for index 0 and return: if (indexPath.row == 0) return;

Comment: i don't need that headers i need if the first cell is selected the second cell want to enable that's it

Comment: then use UITableView Delegate tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: and get selected index like: indexPath.row and call enable action for indexPath.row+1

Answer (score 0):

Using this way you can able to select the current row and enable next row for selecting. You need to handle another way to disable others row in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.checkMark.selected = YES;
    NSString *cellText = cell.textLabel.text;

   if(self.colors.count < indexPath.row+1  ){
    NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:0];
     UITableViewCell *nextCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath];
     nextCell.checkMark.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
   //OR
     nextCell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
}
```